# what would the identity element for wedge products exactly be

Tags: exterior-algebra

i was not sure about the identity element for the wedge product $\wedge$. For $\omega \in \Lambda^kV^{*}$ Would the identity element give
$\omega\wedge 1= -1\wedge \omega$, or $\omega \wedge 1 = 1 \wedge \omega$, or something else and i did not understand this properly? Could anyone give some hint? Thanks in advance and best regards!

Comment: $\bigwedge^0 V^* = k$ is the ground field of $V$, and $1 \in k$ satisfies $1 \wedge \omega = \omega \wedge 1 = 1\omega = \omega$.

Comment: Ah so for this case its the same as treating $1\in \Lambda^0V^{*}$ as a scalar of the "vector" $\omega$, so it simplifies to $\omega \wedge 1 = \omega \cdot 1 = \omega$?

Comment: The identity element has degree zero which is even, so it commutes with everything (as it should).